# JLC2313 stackup with DDR3 fly-by

Tags: pcb-layers, routing, high-speed, soc, ddr3

I’m building a simple SBC based on Allwinner A33 for my undergraduate final project, includes two x8 DDR3 chips. I’m going with 6 layers JLC2313 Stackup 1.2mm thickness (cost reasons). It’s my first DDR3 design and I have a lot of questions.

Their website/field solver suggests 14 mil track on stripline and 5.7 mils on microstrip for SE50 ohms impedance. That’s super thick.

I was wondering if I can use SE60 ohms and 120 ohms for differential pairs on DDR3 (That’ll be 9.4/3.8 mils).

I’ve included the stack up. L1=> Signal, L2=> GND plane, L3=> Signal, L4=> Signal, L5=> Split Power, L6=> Signal.  The prepreg (Dk=4.25) between L3 and L4 is just 5 mil (0.127mm) in thickness. **Would that cause a lot of crosstalk?** Was planning route ACC on L3  and data banks on L4.  Would keeping almost minimum intersection help me out here? I will reference it to the adjacent layers (GND,VDDQ) , separated by cores with a thickness of 14.37 mil (0.365mm).

**Any suggestion on ddr3 layout and layer utilization, especially with JLCPCB’s 6L stack up?**  (Included a preliminary component placement).

**About DDR3 termination, BBB, most of the boards from Bpi, Olimex, OrangePi and even Rpi seems to be termination only the DRAM clock. What about ACC group?**

**DRAM reset signal, Is it a pull-up or down? Is it SoC specific?** DRAM_RESET is active low, but I've seen a couple other designs utilizing a pull down. I’m using H5TC4G83AFR-PBA/PBC DRAM chips.

I understand differential pair’s impedance can be seen as two single ended TL’s impedance coupled with a gap. I’ve tried iCD stackup planner and can’t quite get the bang-on 120 ohms differential geometry right on JLC’s stackup (aware of the 10% tolerance), same story with their website (they seem to be using Si8000). **So, is it weird to maint[image]ain 60Ohm SE and 100Ohm Differential for DDR3 signals?**

I highly appreciate any inputs and suggestions. 
Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Going from 50 ohms to 60 is a 20% difference from recommended to design, that seems like a lot. What DDR3 chip are you using specifically?

Comment: i am using a H5TQ4G4 DDR3 chip.